# Why does specifying the index column in pandas significantly increases the read time of a csv?

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I am seeing a significantly increased read time for a CSV by pandas when I specify the `index_col`. I do not understand the reason behind it. Can you help me understand why that is happening and if that is actually the expected behaviour? Below is the code I am using:

```
import pandas as pd
#save the CSV to be used
pd.DataFrame({'id':np.arange(100000000),'b':np.random.choice(['a','b','c','d'],size=(100000000,),p=[0.25,0.25,0.25,0.25])}).to_csv('df_sp.csv',index=None)
dfpd = pd.read_csv('df_sp.csv')
#read time - 10.3 seconds
dfpd = pd.read_csv('df_sp.csv',index_col='id')
#read time - 1 minute 38.6 seconds
```

In fact, I am seeing significant improvement if I read the dataset without specifying `index_col` and then set the index by `dfpd = dfpd.set_index('id')`. This takes just 1.6 more seconds. Why does pandas not default to always reading the dataframe with `index_col` as a column and then setting it as the index internally with `set_index(index_col)` when `index_col` is specified?

I'm on linux

Adding performance images in 3 slightly different runtime configurations:

Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS

[image: config1]

Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS

[image: config2]

Ubuntu 18.04.5 LTS

[image: config3]

Comment: This doesn't seem intended. Can you file a [bug](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/new?assignees=&labels=Bug%2CNeeds+Triage&template=bug_report.yaml&title=BUG%3A+)?

Comment: I have filed a performance issue. https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/44158 . Does this work as good as filing a bug?

Comment: yes, looks good to me

Comment: can you try with 1.1.x and 1.2.x as well - that will probably help pandas devs figure out where the perf issues might have originated from? I tried 1.1.5 and it doesn't seem to have this issue

Comment: What OS are you running?

Answer (score 1):

I can't reproduce these differences. Using `%timeit` in Jupyter, I get:

```py
import pandas as pd
#save the CSV to be used
pd.DataFrame({'id':np.arange(100000000),'b':np.random.choice(['a','b','c','d'],size=(100000000,),p=[0.25,0.25,0.25,0.25])}).to_csv('df_sp.csv',index=None)

%timeit dfpd1 = pd.read_csv('df_sp.csv')
%timeit dfpd2 = pd.read_csv('df_sp.csv',index_col='id')
```

Results:

```
10.9 s ± 74.3 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
11.6 s ± 10.7 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
```

Edit: Python and pandas versions

```
>>> sys.version
'3.9.7 (default, Sep 16 2021, 08:50:36) \n[Clang 10.0.0 ]'
>>> pd.__version__
'1.3.3'
```

Running on MacOS 11.6 (amd64)

Comment: Can you include your `pandas` version? I can't reproduce OPs results with `pandas 1.1.3` and got the same as yours.

Comment: I used pandas 1.3.3

Comment: My results are : 11.7 s ± 950 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
1min 23s ± 9.39 s per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each). Used foglerit's code as is

Comment: @MiloMinderbinder, I'm on the same version of pandas, on a Mac

Comment: I have run it again and I can confirm that I am getting the issue. Attaching a screenshot for the same if that helps. I am completely lost on how to move ahead on this issue. I am also on pandas 1.3.3 (though I have started testing this on 1.3.4 as well 5 minutes ago). Any suggestions on what I should do? My entire runtime information is available here:  github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/44158

Comment: updated the question to contain the different runtime configurations where I was able to replicate the error